# How to plot in subplots with personal function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, python-xarray

I want to plot one graph for each axes in subplots using a function that I created (e.g. plot_graph(chosen_time)). It would go something like that:

```
times = ['2010-01-01','2010-09-01','2011-01-01']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1)
for i in times:
    axs[?].plot_graph(i)
```

I'm using xarray and tried it with facets, but I found some limitations for my purpose.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have x, y to plot for each time? And, what is `plot_graph`?

Comment: plot_graph() is a function created by me that plots spatial contours (x is longitude, y is latitude, z (color) is the desired variable) for a specific time within the dataset. My goal with this post is to know if I can use my function with subplots to plot each time in each subplot axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this example matches what you want but hope it helps.

In your code, you cannot write as `axs[?]`, instead you need to use `axs[i]`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fuction to plot i-th graph
def plot_graph(i, x, y, z, time):
    axs[i].plot(x, y, z)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)

# set x, y, z, times
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
y = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
z = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
times = ["2010-01-01", "2010-09-01", "2011-01-01"]


# plot i-th subplot
for i in range(3):    
    plot_graph(i, x[i], y[i], z[i], times[i])

plt.show()
```

Comment: That really helped! Thank you.